# If $K$ is normal and $f$ is not epi, can $f(K)$ be normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Robert Ash's [*Basic Abstract Algebra.*](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Algebra.html)

I've read and seen the following proposition with proof:

> If $f:G\to H$ is an epimorphism and $K$ is normal, then $f(K)$ is also normal.

I have a further question: Suppose $f$ is not an epimorphism, can $f(K)$ still be normal at least in some specific cases? It seems to me that in some cases, we could have $hf(K)h^{-1}=f(K)$ for all $h\in H$ and yet, some $h\in H$ won't have a $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=h$.

Comment: That's precisely the problem: $f(K)$ will be normal in $f(G)$ but not necessarily in larger subgroups of $H$.

Comment: The answer to the question that you have asked is clearly yes. Of course it can be normal, for example when each of the groups is abelian. The point is that it is $f(G)$ is not necessarily normal in $H$ when $f$ is not an epimorphism.